# Haskell using typeclasses inside type signatures

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-signature

Assuming a simple typeclass constrained signature:

```
f :: (Eq a, Num b) => a -> b
f str = 4
```

I was wondering why these didn't work

```
f :: (Eq a) -> (Num b)
f str = 4

f :: Eq -> Num
f str = 4
```

I know that type classes have the kind `* -> Constraint`, whereas the type signatures only accept kinds of `*`.

But my question is why is there this restriction? Why can't typeclasses be used like types? What would be the advantages and disadvantages of allowing the ability to use typeclasses like types?

Comment: What could one do with a value of type `Eq`?

Comment: It's just a contrived example. I'm not interested in the function implementation.

Comment: What about `Functor`? That's `(* -> *) -> Constraint`. How should one write that down? `(Functor f) something` or `(Functor f) something? What if `something` needs to hold another constraint? Even more, what if I want to use the _same_ type at different places, e.g. `([Ord a] -> [Ord a])`. The latter seems rather verbose. And as a last piece of thought: what about `Num a, Ord a, Show a`? How would one use your syntax in this situation?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I know, I'm positing the question to help you explore why there might be such a restriction...

Comment: @Zeta well I don't suggest to replace the current style of using typeclasses, just is there any reasons to not be able to use typeclasses as types, other than verbosity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is (if we neglect unboxed types) only one kind whose types actually have any values: `*`. All other kinds don't contain types as such, but just "type-level entities". The compiler can use those to determine *what to do* with the actual types and their values around, but it's never possible to have at runtime a value of a "type" with some kind like `* -> Constraint`.

That `*` is **the** kind for value-types is just a rule of the game. It's a good thing to have, for much the same reason it's a good idea to have a strong static type system which prevents nonsensical conversions at runtime. <sup>[***Wat??***](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat)</sup> Or, let's take it literally, for the same reason you can't just hop your king over your pawns, no matter how appealing that feature might look in a particular situation you've run into.

If some extension did allow making values from non-`*`-kinded types, in particular `* -> Constraint`, we'd need a whole bunch of non-obvious definitions to make it clear how these "class-values" are actually supposed to be used. Likely, it would amount to a record type containing the class' methods as a dictionary. But, how exactly... the specification would be pretty much of a nightmare. And complicating the language itself this way is in no way worth the expenditure, since **1.** the standard way of using type classes is just fine for at least 95% of all applications, and **2.** when you do need reified type classes, you can quite easily do so with GADTs, ConstraintKinds, or even plain old manually-defined dictionary records. None of that requires distorting the fundamental ideas of how the language treats values, as non-`*`-types would.

---

Anyway... let's explore for a moment how this *might* work. One thing is for sure: it would *not* allow you to write stuff anything as simple as `f str = 4`!

Consider

```
f1 :: forall a, b . Eq a -> Num b
```

Both `Eq a, Num b :: Constraint`, so we'd have values of type of kind `Constraint`. That would basically be a particular dictionary of methods for a given instance. So the implementation of `f1` would have to look something like

```
f1 (EqDict (d_eq :: a -> a -> Bool))
       = NumDict { dict_fromInteger = ??? :: Integer -> b
                 , dict_plus        = ??? :: b -> b -> b
                 , ...
                 , dict_signum      = ??? :: b -> b
                 }
```

Evidently there is no meaningful way to define all those methods in the result. All you could do with such a "class-function" is to "project" from a stronger class to a weaker one. E.g. you could define

```
monadApp :: forall m . Monad m -> Applicative m
monadApp (MonadDict {dict_return = d_ret, dict_bind = d_bd})
        = ApplicativeDict { dict_pure = d_ret
                          , dict_app = \fs vs -> d_bd fs (\f -> d_bd vs $ d_ret . f) }
```

That specific one would be, in fact, somewhat useful, but only because `Monad` ([still, but not for long!](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal)) lacks `Applicative` as a superclass which it should simply have. Normally, there shouldn't be much reason having to explicitly "downgrade" any classes, because superclass-relations (or tuple-ConstraintKinds) do just that automatically.

Comment: So what you're saying, is that if typeclasses were available as type variables, we would need some way of deconstructing the constraint value, which would now be probably implemented as a dictionary. Whereas what we have now using the `=>` operator in the type universe, it's not saying that `a` in `Eq a` is a constraint, but that whatever `a` is, it just an instance of `Eq`. I've always considered typeclasses to be just another type. But you call them "type-entities".

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. Type classes are not "just another type", like OO classes, at all. Rather think of them as mathematical theorems, particular properties that various types fulfill. The `instance`s are then proofs to those theorems, for particular types.

Comment: I'm reading this paper now http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3837 & http://i.cs.hku.hk/~bruno/papers/Objects.pdf

It appears there's a way to reconcile these constructs together into something more general.

Comment: You can generalise everything into something more general... but normally, in Haskell you're best off to think of _types_ as plain `data` (which can actually get you pretty far into OO territory!), and _type classes_ as something completely orthogonal.

Answer (score 4):

Type variables may appear more than once in a type signature:

```
f :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

Writing the above as

```
f :: Eq a -> Eq a -> Eq a -> Bool
```

looks inconvenient. Worse, we might have more than one constraint on `a`:

```
g :: (Show a, Eq a) => a -> Bool
```

How would we write this in the alternative notation?

```
g :: (Show & Eq) a -> Bool    -- ??
```

Forgetting the `a` completely as you suggest in the last example makes signatures
ambiguous: consider

```
h1 :: (Eq a)       => a -> a -> a -> a -> Bool
h2 :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> a -> b -> b -> Bool
```

These are quite different signatures: you can call `h2 1 2 [1] [2]` but not `h1 1 2 [1] [2]`
since the latter requires the four arguments to be of the same type.
After the proposed convention is used, they are reduced to the same signature:

```
h12 :: Eq -> Eq -> Eq -> Eq -> Bool
```

Is the call `h12 1 2 [1] [2]` valid? The above signature is too ambiguous to tell.

Comment: Using just `Eq` does seem ambiguous, but I would probably assume as new user, that it simply means all of the parameters must be an instance of Eq, and there are no further constraints. So they could be all the same type or it could be all different types, it's "unconstrained". The `(Show & Eq) a` seem like it's same issue as with using union/sum types. You would need some sort of union of Show & Eq.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai So `f :: Eq -> Eq -> Bool ; f x y = (x==y)` would be invalid? Under your interpretation it would correspond to `f :: (Eq a, Eq b) => a -> b -> Bool ; f x y = (x==y)`, which triggers a type error since you can't compare things of different types `a` and `b`.

Comment: I would assume that `Eq` by itself would be implicitly prefixed with `forall` for all `Eq`. What that would mean, is that each of your type parameters would be any type that is an instance of Eq.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai If it must be of both types `Int` and `String` (and _all_ other `Eq` types), the only value you can pass to such function is bottom, i.e. `undefined` or `error "message"`. You can not pass `4` (since it's not a string) or `"abc"` (not an integer). You can actually try this in current GHC by declaring `type MyEq = forall a. Eq a => a` and then `f :: MyEq -> MyEq -> ...`. If instead it must be of _some_ `Eq` type, then all the types would be regarded as being different, e.g. the first `Eq` could be `Int`, the second one `String` -- preventing one to compare `x==y` between them.

Comment: Yea I see how a type signature like that does introduce the possibility for failure at runtime.